# Extension of a Continuous function on a dense subset to its closure.

Tags: real-analysis

A continuous function on $\mathbb Q\cap [0 \, 1]$ can be extended to a continuous function on [0  1] -Prove.

We have the result that a uniformly continuous function on a set A can be extended continuously to $\overline A$. I am unable to apply the result in this case because I don’t know whether the given function is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb Q \cap [0\,1]. $ Please help.

Comment: Is the codomain of the original function also $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$?

Comment: The codomain is not specified in the question. I presume it is R.

Comment: Does the codomain play any part in the solution to this problem? I can’t see how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false. Let

$$f:\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]\to[0,1]:q\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }0\le q<\frac12\sqrt2\\
1,&\text{if }\frac12\sqrt2<q\le 1\;
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is continuous on its domain, but it cannot be extended to a function on $[0,1]$ that is continuous at $\frac12\sqrt2$.

Comment: Does this imply that f is not uniformly continuous??

Comment: @LawrenceMano: Yes. And you can easily check that there are rational numbers $p$ and $q$ arbitrarily close together such that $|f(p)-f(q)|=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it’s very clear to me.

Comment: @LawrenceMano: You're very welcome.