# When can we get an continous extension of a continous function defined on a dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Suppose $X,Y$ are metric spaces and $E$ is dense in $X$ and $f:E\rightarrow Y$ is continuous. Then, which of the following are true generally?
>
> 1. $Y=\mathbb{R}^k \Rightarrow \exists$ a continuous extension.
> 2. $Y$ is compact $\Rightarrow \exists$ a continuous extension.
> 3. $Y$ is complete $\Rightarrow \exists$ a continuous extension. (AC$_\omega$)
> 4. $E$ is countable & $Y$ is complete $\Rightarrow \exists$ a continuous extension.

Answer to all is negative by using the function $\arctan( \frac{1}{ x - \sqrt{2} })$ as said by [Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221734/688539).

So, my question is, what is the minimal condition required on $Y$ such that $f$ is continous then?

Comment: the answer is not negative. Uniform continuity of $f$ and completeness of $Y$ implies there is a uniformly continuous extension $f:\overline{E}=X\to Y$.

Comment: Thanks @peek-a-boo

Comment: those 4 statements are true, so I’m not sure what your question is. What I just said is that (3) is true. The remaining statements are special cases of (3). For example, $\Bbb{R}^k$ is complete, so that proves (1). Next, compact metric spaces are complete, so that proves (2). Lastly, (4) is clearly a special case of (3). And also, the conclusion of (3) can be strengthened to “there is a uniformly continuous extension”.

Comment: The question in that link was "All these are true if $f$ is uniformly continuous.  What if $f$ is merely continuous?"  The negative result was specifically for the case of $f$ being continuous.

Comment: I checked again, there the statements are al true only for Uniform continous . I am asking conditions for just  continuious @peek-a-boo

Comment: … you should reword your question then

Comment: Also, even if you correct the wording in your question, there is no real way to fix this ‘theorem’. Adding more conditions on $X$ or $Y$ won’t really help. Continuity alone is just not strong enough to ensure existence of extensions. The counterexample (to the correct question) is a very strong one. A simpler example to think about is $f(x)=\arctan(1/x)$ defined on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. This is continuous, bounded, but has no continuous extension to the origin. Here, $E$ is just $X$ minus one point, yet there is no extension, which shows that even a single point causes lots of issues.

Comment: How were you to identify that adjusting conditions on $X$ or $Y$ won't be able to fix? I suppose I should've been able to understand it through the example, but I couldn't, so  could you expand the idea more elaborately?

Comment: I said that because the example $\arctan(1/x)$ shows it, no matter how much you try to fiddle around $X,E,Y$. I made $X$ any subset of reals containing an interval around the origin, and $E=X\setminus\{0\}$, which is just one point less, and I can make $Y$ be compact, which is as good as can get. Really, at this stage if you want to get a “true” theorem, then the only way I see is to make the absurdly trivial assumption that $Y$ is a singleton set, because then $f$ obviously has a continuous extension, because it is constant.

Comment: Heck, even if $Y$ has only two points, the statement is false. Let $f(x)=0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $f(x)=1$ on $(0,\infty)$. There’s no continuous extension to the origin. If the sought-after theorem cannot accomodate such a simple function, then it obviously has no hope of holding any water.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Very helpful discussion in thinking about proofs. But, Why do you say compact is as good as it can get? @peek-a-boo

Comment: Uniform extension theorem: Let $(X, d) $ and $(Y, d')$ be two metric spaces with

 1) $D\subset X$ dense. 

2) $f:D\to Y$ uniformly continuous. 

3) $(Y, d') $ is complete. 

Then $\exists! \hat{f}:X\to Y $ uniformly continuous such that $\hat{f}\mid_{D}=f$

Comment: in terms of smallness of sets, we usually go finite set, compact set, closed& bounded set, etc but anyway, even with 2 points in $Y$, the statement is false. This really shows you continuity is not the right property to look at.

Comment: "Extension of continuous function " is not an easy task. One need something more than continuity (like uniform continuity) or tools like "Titze extension theorem "